# List all months between two dates sequentially?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to list out all the months between two dates across a single *row* in Excel. So far I have this:

> SEQUENCE( ,"End date"-"Start Date" +1, "Start Date")

This does almost what I'd like, but lists every single DAY between the two dates. What simple fix should I make such that it would increment by month and display month/year in order? Thanks

Comment: you can use EOMONTH, I don't have time to write out full answer but using his and IF should get you what you're after

Answer (score 3):

Put the start date in **A1** and the end date in **A2**.  Pick a cell and enter:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),SEQUENCE(1,DATEDIF(A1,A2,"M")+1,MONTH(A1),1),1)
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

This is because this:

```
=SEQUENCE(1,DATEDIF(A1,A2,"M")+1,MONTH(A1),1)
```

produces a sequential list of month numbers *10,11,12,13,14,15,16*. and month 13 is January of the following year.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is easier or not, but you might try:

=EDATE(StartDate,SEQUENCE(1,CountOfMonths,0,1))

If you don't have the number of months, just the start and end dates, then try:

```
=EDATE(StartDate,
       SEQUENCE(1,
                1+DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"M")
        )
      )
```

As a single line, that's:

=EDATE(StartDate,SEQUENCE(1,1+DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"M")))

EDATE gets you the date n months aways.
The DATEDIF gets the number of months between, but usually you'll want Jan-Dec to be 12 rather than 11; that's why the extra +1.
SEQUENCE builds the array of "deltas" to pass to EDATE. The first argument to SEQUENCE says to keep the array as a single row. The number of columns is the count of the months. The first cell in the array will be 0, then 1, 2, and so on until it reaches the full count.

I've been using this approach for a while when I need dynamic date columns.

Answer (score 0):

*I do believe that you are looking for this only:*

[image]

- Formula in cell AN2:

  ```
  =IF(ROW()=2,0,IFERROR(INDEX(MONTH(EDATE(AL$1,ROW(AN$1:INDEX(AN:AN,DATEDIF(AL$1,AL$2,"m"))))),COUNT(AN$1:AN1)),""))
  ```
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.
- You may replace 0 with 1 (for first month i.e January).